# how can I troubleshoot meteor just hanging?

Tags: meteor

Hi I am trying out meteor for first time today.

my symptoms: meteor just hangs when trying to connect to port 3000 (it is listening, checked with lsof and looking at ps) a mongo instance is started on port 3002 but i can not connect to it with mongo (so perhaps neither can node ?)

background: I do already have mongo 2.0.3 installed and running (can it be a conflict?)

What can I do to troubleshoot and get meteor started ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site was bugging me to accept an answer or start a bounty...So here is explanation of my comment:

> localhost on my machine resolves to ipv6 address first and meteor
>   binds only to 127.0.0.1.

So to answer the specific question of "how to troubleshoot":

I used `lsof -i` to verify that the meteor mongo instance was actually listening.  This showed me that is was listening on 127.0.0.1.  This eliminated the concept of mongo not listening.  next i did `host my machine's name` and noticed the ipv6 came back first. this sparked a hunch and led me to force meteor to connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, check that port 3000 is open `netstat -a`

try a `telnet localhost 3000`

Use firefox extension TamperData or any other flow analysis tools to see what's going on at the HTTP level http://tamperdata.mozdev.org/

Have you tried to run against the bundled node and mongodb ?

Comment: Figured it out. localhost on my machine resolves to ipv6 address first and meteor binds only to 127.0.0.1. Great got that out of the way, now to learning